# Serverless signalR: Adding a user to a group and sending a message to the group simultaneously in upstream

Tags: azure, azure-functions, signalr, signalr-hub, azure-signalr

I wrote the following code with the hope of adding a user to a group and sending a message to the user's group simultaneously. I can see the connections established per the signalR's blade on my Azure's Portal but I cannot conclude whether or not the user has become a member of the group after returning this function.

```cs
    [Function("OnConnected")]
    [SignalROutput(HubName = "myhub")]
    public async Task<object[]> OnConnectedAsync([SignalRTrigger("myhub", "connections", "connected")] SignalRInvocationContext invocationContext)
    {
        var username = "userA";
        var groupName = "groupA";
        return
        [
            new SignalRGroupAction(SignalRGroupActionType.Add)
            {
                GroupName = groupName,
                UserId = username
            },
            new SignalRMessageAction("NewUserConnected")
            {
                GroupName = groupName,
                Arguments = [userName]
            }
        ];
    }
```

Does the function's implementation above exhibit a right approach to add a user to the group and send a message to the group at the same time?

> Note: Before writing this code, I tried to add the user to the group by the following line of code while having the function above report `SignalRMessageAction` object but it threw an exception:

```cs
await UserGroups.AddToGroupAsync(userName, groupName);
```

Apparently signalR's SDK does not like the line above in the context of upstreams.

Comment: Which exception did the SignalR's SDK throw?

Comment: Also, what is your expected result? Do you wish to send the newly added user the group message or not?

Comment: @AlexPshul Yes I'd list to add a user to a group while sending a message to the users in the same group.

Comment: I tried adding a user to a group and to  send a message to the group using this SignalR output binding using this [DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-signalr-service-output?tabs=in-process&pivots=programming-language-csharp)

Comment: So better understand, if you use the two output bindings, the user doesn't get a message?
If so, maybe the best solution would be to figure out what was the exception when using the SDK. Can you edit your answer to include the error?

Answer (score 0):

The code below adds a user to a group and sends a message to the group. The Azure Function `SendMessage` is designed to handle POST requests and send messages to a SignalR group named "myGroup" using output binding.

- It reads the request body to extract `userId` and `message`.
- It adds the `userId` to the SignalR group "myGroup".
- It sends the `message` to the SignalR group "myGroup".
- Azure Functions SignalR Service output binding [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-signalr-service-output?tabs=in-process&pivots=programming-language-csharp).

**Adds a user to a group and sends a message to the group:**

```
 [FunctionName("SendMessage")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> SendMessage(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post")] HttpRequest req,
        [SignalR(HubName = "sampathravi90ravi")] IAsyncCollector<SignalRGroupAction> signalRGroupActions,
        [SignalR(HubName = "sampathravi90ravi")] IAsyncCollector<SignalRMessage> signalRMessages,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
        dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);

        string userId = data?.userId;
        string message = data?.message;

        if (userId != null && message != null)
        {
            // Add user to group
            await signalRGroupActions.AddAsync(
                new SignalRGroupAction
                {
                    UserId = userId,
                    GroupName = "myGroup",
                    Action = GroupAction.Add
                });

            // Send message to group
            await signalRMessages.AddAsync(
                new SignalRMessage
                {
                    GroupName = "myGroup",
                    Target = "newMessage",
                    Arguments = new[] { message }
                });

            log.LogInformation($"Sent message: {message} to group myGroup for user {userId}");

            return new OkResult();
        }
        else
        {
            log.LogError("Either userId or message not found in the request body.");
            return new BadRequestObjectResult("Please pass userId and message in the request body.");
        }
    }
```

```json
{

"userId": "userId1",

"message": "Hello, world!"

}
```

**Output:**
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Sampath but yours does not apply to dotnet-isolated functions.

Comment: checking with  dotnet-isolated functions